# Qual a tradução mais adequada para a frase "I just wanted to get to do what I got to do."

Tags: português-brasileiro

Na seguinte frase de Adam Sandler, qual seria a tradução mais adequada para a parte destacada?

> I never thought about what people would say about me. I was just a young guy who was excited to become a comedian and an actor, and **I just wanted to get to do what I got to do**.

Comment: Por essas e por outras é que não se pode/deve responder em comentários, @Lambie... ;) Agora que já há uma resposta, vou apagar o meu comentário.

Comment: @ANeves Pois é, agora a resposta está sofrendo do que chamo "o grande silêncio". People ask for stuff, and when they get the right thing, they ignore it. Tenho minhas teorias a respeito desse fenômeno. :) – Lambie 26 mins ago

Comment: @staf , não me deste tempo para concluir: no entanto encontram-se alguns exemplos do tipo de *had got to go* na literatura.

Comment: Obrigado @Jacinto Considero relevante incluir traduções alternativas, ainda que não ideais no contexto específico da pergunta. Afinal, o objetivo do SE é construir um corpus aberto e nem todos os que chegarem nessa página por um mecanismo de busca estarão interessados exatamente no contexto da entrevista. Mas devo dizer que a prolongada discussão me fez perder o interesse em contribuir para essa pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to get to do what I got to do.

- Eu só queria conseguir fazer o que consegui fazer.

*get to do* significa em inglês:  conseguir fazer algo

> What did you get to do last night?

Que foi que você conseguiu fazer ontem à noite?

Comment: A resposta está correta. Seria interessante dizer o porque do "downvote".

Answer (score -1):

Eu já entendo a frase como tendo um significado levemente diferente das outras respostas e traduziria como:

"Eu só queria ter a oportunidade de fazer aquilo que eu consegui fazer."

Na ocasião, o jovem só queria ter a oportunidade de fazer aquilo que ele conseguiu fazer para tornar-se um comediante.

Comment: O verbo: get to do (passado/got to do), só tem um significado. Você traduziu: I just wanted to get to do what I had to do. got aqui não pode ser precisar.

Comment: @Lambie  Tens razão. Vou modificar.

Comment: De qualquer forma a tua resposta é a que melhor traduz o idioma.  +1.